# Prestashop redirect loop

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, prestashop

I have a site with 2 languages. I disabled browser detection, and I use geolocation for currency. I want to redirect users who have the Euro currency to `en`, and users who have Lei to `ro`. I trie to make a redirect but have this error:

> This web page has a redirect loop.

Here is my code:

```
if($this->context->cookie->id_currency !== 'RON'){
    Tools::redirect('domain/en/');
}
else{
    Tools::redirect('domain/ro/');
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add the error you're getting.

Comment: This web page has redirect loop

Comment: Perhaps you mean to write `id_language`, because you don't change the currency after redirecting, and it makes senses that your currency stays the same = you get redirected forever.